# Asp.net compare validator to validate date

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, date, comparevalidator

As you all know Compare validators can be used to validate dates and check based on operator type (<, <= , >= etc). I have set the `cultureinvariantvalues="true"` property to validate two textbox controls that hold dates. I have to constrain them such that the start date must be earlier than the finish date. The validation seems to fail when I type a descriptive date like below:

```
StartDate: Tuesday, 21 February 2012

FinishDate: Wednesday, 22 February 2012
```

Even though 22nd is larger than 21st the validation fails. The markup I used is below. If for any reason you need format info, here it is `dddd, dd MMMM yyyy`

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="cvtxtStartDate" runat="server" 
       controltocompare="txtFinishDate" 
       cultureinvariantvalues="true" 
       display="Dynamic" 
       enableclientscript="true" 
       controltovalidate="txtStartDate" 
       errormessage="Start date must be earlier than finish date" 
       type="Date" 
       setfocusonerror="true" 
       operator="LessThanEqual" 
       text="Start date must be earlier than finish date">
```

Comment: hey are you using single compare validator for two textboxes?

Comment: @JayaPrakashRokkam Yup it suffices. Either way the validation will happen

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this approach, First Enter the Start Date and Check the Compare Validator with the End Date textbox:

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="cvtxtStartDate" runat="server" 
     ControlToCompare="txtStartDate" cultureinvariantvalues="true" 
     display="Dynamic" enableclientscript="true"  
     ControlToValidate="txtFinishDate" 
     ErrorMessage="Start date must be earlier than finish date"
     type="Date" setfocusonerror="true" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" 
     text="Start date must be earlier than finish date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: +1 for the best solution. If I have another account, +1 for the simplicity. Good job.

Answer (score 6):

Compare validator has the type=date.But that date type is constrained to accept only particular format of date i.e ToShortDateString().
If the date format of the two textboxes to be compared is in some other format like ToLongDateString() or some format specified by ToString("dd MMMM,yyyy") the comparision does not work.
CustomValidator isonly option.
If you want to use compare validator only then

```
textstartdate.text=Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
textfinishdate=Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator4" runat="server" 
                    ControlToCompare="textstartdate" ControlToValidate="textfinishdate" 
                    CultureInvariantValues="True" 
                    ErrorMessage="Date should be greater than booking date." 
                    Operator="GreaterThanEqual" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try custom Validator and at the code behind at onservervalidate event convert the text to DateTime and then do the comparision.

```
protected void DateTimeComparision_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text) < Convert.ToDateTime(txtFinishDate.Text);
    }
```

Comment: custom validator is my last resort. I do know how to use all of these validators i just wanted to know if the compare validators support only dates of format 'm/d/y'

Answer (score 0):

```
function FromAndToDateValidate() {
try {
    var StartDate = new Date();
    StartDate = $("#dtpFromDate").val();

    var EndDate = new Date();
    EndDate = $("#dtpToDate").val();
    args.IsValid = (StartDate <= EndDate);
}
catch (ex) {
    alert(ex);
}
}
```