# Compare date with today in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, datetime

i have a `textbox` which takes input date from user. now i want to make a `validator` which checks either date is greater then today or not.

i tried this link but it has some problems http://forums.asp.net/t/1116715.aspx/1

if i give this date **`25/03/2013`** it is correct but if give **`01/04/2013`**, it says it is less then today.

**

**Update**

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtReturnDate"
                                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Date should be greater then  today" ForeColor="Red"
                                Operator="GreaterThan" ValidationGroup="VI">Date should be greater then  today</asp:CompareValidator>
```

**

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: What's your comparison code? I hope you are not trying to compare strings? (you can still compare it, but it will need different representation)

Comment: you have to check current culture : it may takes `01/04/2013` as `4 Jan 2013` not as `1 April 2013`

Comment: Show us some code! You did set the type to `Date`, didn't you?

Comment: Can you show us your code? It is impossible to say what you did from your question.

Comment: @DawoodAbbasi Looks like typical Culture manipulation problem. Try to work out current Culture/UI Culture. Try to force culture on session start, and see if that changes any behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i have done this by

```
CompareValidator1.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below code to compare specified date with todays date

```
string date = "01/04/2013";
                DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (myDate > DateTime.Today)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("greater than");
                }
               else
                {
                 Console.WriteLine("Less Than");
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `25/3/2013` is unambiguosly `25th March 2013`, however with the wrong culture settings, `01/04/13` could be `4th january 2013` which is indeed before today's date. I assume you thought you were entering `1st April 2013` which would be after.

The solution is one of

- Use an unambiguous date format when typing into your textbox (`2013-01-04` for 1st April)
- Use a date selector component which exposes the actual date
- parse the date in the way you expect it (`dd/MM/yyyy`)

The problem with `asp:CompareValidator` is that it does not seem to understand that dates can be formatted differently, and uses just the `ToShortDateString` variant of a `DateTime` to compare (whoever implemented this should be shot!). The solution according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372901/asp-net-compare-validator-to-validate-date) seems to be to use a `CustomValidator`

```
protected void DateTimeComparision_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy") > DateTime.Today 
}
```

Comment: i take input in 01/04/2013 form which is actually 1st April 2013 and my culture is "en-GB"

Answer (score 0):

It thinks 1/4/2013 is the 4th January. You should create a DateTime object using the new DateTime(Year, Month, Day) constructor an the comparisson will work correctly, i.e

```
var compareDate = new DateTime(2013,4,1)
bool afterToday = DateTime.Today < compareDate
```

Answer (score 0):

this kinds of date validations should be permormed on the client side..in my Application we have used the following code

```
convert: function (d) {
        /* Converts the date in d to a date-object. The input can be:
        a date object: returned without modification
        an array      : Interpreted as [year,month,day]. NOTE: month is 0-11.
        a number     : Interpreted as number of milliseconds
        since 1 Jan 1970 (a timestamp) 
        a string     : Any format supported by the javascript engine, like
        "YYYY/MM/DD", "MM/DD/YYYY", "Jan 31 2009" etc.
        an object     : Interpreted as an object with year, month and date
        attributes.  **NOTE** month is 0-11. */
        return (
        d.constructor === Date ? d :
        d.constructor === Array ? new Date(d[0], d[1], d[2]) :
        d.constructor === Number ? new Date(d) :
        d.constructor === String ? new Date(d) :
        typeof d === "object" ? new Date(d.year, d.month, d.date) :
        NaN
    );

 isFutureDate: function (a) {
        var now = new Date();
        return (a > now) ? true : false;
    },
```

Now call the above functions like this (isFutureDate(convert("your form date value"))).

Comment: If you're perfoming client-side validation that's great but you should never rely on it -implement server validation too.

Comment: yup if the user explicitely turns off enable javascript option in his browser then this code falls flat on its face..this was just a quick fix to his problem thats all.. :)