# How to use compare validator to compare the data between two dropdownlists values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, comparevalidator

I have two `DropDownLists` populated with `Year-Dates`, and I want to show an error message in the case where the second ddls value is less than the first ddls value.

This is the code I have used so far, and it doesn't work:

```
  <asp:CompareValidator 
       ID="cvEndYear2" Operator="GreaterThan" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" 
       ValidationGroup="Save" ControlToValidate="ddlEndYear" Display="Dynamic" 
       ValueToCompare="ddlStartYear" ErrorMessage="Greater Than" SetFocusOnError="true">
  </asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372901/asp-net-compare-validator-to-validate-date

Comment: If it doesn't work, what does it instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `ControlToCompare` and the `Operator`:

```
<asp:CompareValidator 
   ID="cvEndYear2" Operator="GreaterThan" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" 
   ValidationGroup="Save" 
   ControlToValidate="ddlEndYear" Display="Dynamic" 
   ControlToCompare="ddlStartYear"
   Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
   Type="Integer"
   ErrorMessage="The end year must be greater/equal the start year" SetFocusOnError="true">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: either use ``ControlToCompare`` or ``ValueToCompare``, not both at same time

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: thanks. However, msdn [mentions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.controltocompare(v=vs.110).aspx) that: "If both properties are set, the ControlToCompare property takes precedence". Since OP wants to compare two controls he has to use `ControlToCompare`. Is that correct?

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for clarification, did'nt knew that bit, now will keep in mind that :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the type, specify the type of data which would be in the textboxes :

```
 <asp:CompareValidator 
       ..........
       ..........
       ControlToValidate="ddlStartYear" 
       ControlToCompare="ddlEndYear"
       Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
       Type="Integer">
  </asp:CompareValidator>
```

You might want to have a look [at this tutorial](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/compare-validator/)

Comment: [`ValueToCompare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.valuetocompare(v=vs.110).aspx) compares with a constant value, OP wants to compare with a value of another dropdownlist.