# Text Box Validation With Two Textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i check if a text in of one textbox is equal to or greater than the text in another textbox ?

I have tried range validator and compare validator but cant get anything to work.

Comment: Did you heard about custom validator use client side scripts to validate this sort of things... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/9eee01cx(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: what do you want to compare string or number?

Comment: I want  to compare numbers can you please post the code. @ManojNaik

Comment: Don't let others write code for you.

Comment: @SwornimNepal It seems that you are using .net framework 4.5 .JFYI, CompareValidator Control will work upto .net framework 4. If you want to use this control then you have to use .net framework 4 or else find any other alternatives of CompareValidator control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#:

```
double a = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);
double b = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text);

if (a == b)
{
    // Do things
}
```

ASP:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1793666.aspx?Compare+two+numeric+text+box

Comment: thanks but what if i want to write a validation expression ?

Comment: `if (a == b) TextBox3.Text = "equal"; else if (a > b) TextBox3.Text = "a > b";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CompareValidator`, and fill the `ControlToValidate` and `ControlToCompare` with your Textboxes IDs as below :

```
<asp:CompareValidator 
       ID="cvEndYear2" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" runat="server"
       ValidationGroup="Validate" ControlToValidate="YourFirstTextBoxID"  
       ControlToCompare="YourSecondTextBoxID" ErrorMessage="" SetFocusOnError="true">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

You can have a look at [this](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/compare-validator/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997560/how-to-use-compare-validator-to-compare-the-data-between-two-dropdownlists-value) .

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (double.Parse(TextBox1.Text) > double.Parse(TextBox2.Text))
        {
            // 1 greater than 2
        }
        else
        {
            // 1 less than or equal to 2
        }
```